# How can I create an horizontal ListView in Android with fixed number of items?

Tags: android, listview, horizontallist

I searched for a few hours over the internet but I didn't find any example or documentation explaining how to create an horizontal list view with fixed number of elements.

Basically, I would like to have, let's say 3 elements out of n(total number of elements) which are displayed on the screen without taking into consideration the size of the scree. The elements can be bigger or smaller proportionate to the screen but the number of visible elements should be the same, fixed. see the image.

How can I do that? Any hint is appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use [a `ViewPager` configured to show multiple items](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html). Or, use a horizontal-scrolling `RecyclerView` where you attempt to set the item size based on the available space for the `RecyclerView`. Or, if there will be very few children, use a `HorizontalScrollView` wrapped around a horizontal `LinearLayout`, where once again you attempt to set the size of the children based on the available space of the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TwoWayWiew third party library (i dont really recommend this solution),  or if you want to avoid to use lib for this, just use RecyclerView, and you can set HORIZONTAL param to layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a ListView for this, but a RecyclerView instead. Performance is better in a RecyclerView and I honestly find them easier to work with. You can allow for horizonatal scrolling via the LayoutManager for your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

If don't mind scrolling horizontally by 3 items you could use a `ViewPager` with each `View` containing a `LinearLayout` (orientation horizontal) with three of your elements that have a 
`android:layout_width="0dp"` and an 
`andriod:layout_weight="1"` 
for even distribution.

When you "scroll" you would just animate the next "page" into the screen bringing in the next 3 elements.

This might not be the most elegant solution but I think it would behave the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

use the linear layout with its orientation set as horizontal under the relative layout

Comment: Ok, but this doesn;t resolve my problem. My problem is not to set an horizontal scroll view. My problem is to set a fixed number of visible items of a scroll list view